# Xcpretty not working when running xcode ui tests in parallel

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-ui-testing

I've started to run my ui tests in parallel, in order to improve performance. However, when using xcpretty, I don't get now which tests have passed nor what made the tests fail (I only get which tests have failed). Is there any way to solve this? Or an alternative to xcpretty that works with the outputs in the parallel tests. I want to have a nice terminal output, as when using sequential testing.

This is my script:

```sh
  xcodebuild \
    -workspace './code/ios/myApp/myApp.workspace' \
    -scheme 'myApp' \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' \
    test | xcpretty -c
```

This is the output I got when running tests sequentially (And the output I want to continue having when running them in parallel):

```
Selected tests

[15:35:45]: ▸ Test Suite UITests.xctest started

[15:35:45]: ▸ RegisterTest

[15:36:48]: ▸ ✗ testRegisterBrazil, failed - Couldn't find: 
"homeBottomBar_myAccountButton" Button

[15:42:50]: ▸ ✓ testRegisterUSA (61.241 seconds)

[15:42:50]: ▸    Executed 4 tests, with 1 failures (1 unexpected) in 425.314 (425.319) seconds
```

This is the output I get now:

```
Failing tests:

    UITests:

        RegisterTest.testRegisterBrazil()
** TEST FAILED **
```